# Hidden PDF elements in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, pdf, itext

we are displaying pdf files in our iPad application using Quartz Core (CGPdfDocumentRef...), but we noticed that some of the pdf files contains elements that are not visible when viewing the pdf file in Acrobat Reader but they are rendered in our application. For example this are objects that are used for printing or as additional layout information. Sometimes it is even hard to find them using Adobe Acrobat X.

I see two options to solve the problem:

1. Find out a way not to render these elements in our application.
2. Write a custom tool or use an exisiting tool to convert these pdf files to remove all hidden elements. It seems that there is no easy existing solution for this. I am developing a tool for some preparation tasks using iText and C#, perhaps there is a way to solve it using this library.

Does somebody have an idea how for one of these approaches???

Comment: Good point, added the question!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are seeing printer marks that are displayed alongside page edges. If so, there are a few situations: 
1. The marks are included in an optional content group that is marked as invisible. Optional content is ignored by CGPDF API and it is always displayed, there is nothing you can do here. 
2. The marks are outside page CropBox and you display the page using the MediaBox, in this situation you have to clip the page content at CropBox. 
If you can make a file available, I can take a look at it and tell you the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, here is one example pdf file:
www.hi-benny.de/Projects/Catalogs/resources/Catalogs/Catalog_011_Otto_Brandneu3-2012/Seite.pdf

Comment: The PDF file is not available for download, maybe I do not have the right to download it.

Comment: Sorry, this is the correct file: http://www.hi-benny.de/Projekte/catalogs/resources/Catalogs/Catalog_011_Otto_Brandneu3-2012/Seite.pdf

Comment: I displayed the file using my code from here: http://ipdfdev.com/2011/03/23/display-a-pdf-page-on-the-iphone-and-ipad/ and it was displayed the same way like Adobe Reader. The printer marks in the page corners are visible also in Adobe Reader. Can you post a screenshot of how the page is displayed on your system and indicate on the image the content that should not be visible?